# Is there a way to assert that an attribute has been set on a unittest mock object?

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, testing, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

In the following code, is there a way to assert that the `query` attribute has been set if search is a mock object? Or if `query` was the mock object, is there a way to do it?

```
search.query = Q('bool', must=must)
```

So far I've found out that Python unittest.mock only supports asserting that mocks have been called as functions. Also the **setattr** magic method can not be mocked so `search.__setattr__` can not be used to assert the above.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe I misunderstood your point, but why not simply run the code under test and afterwards check that `search` has got that expected attribute `query` and that `search.query` holds the expected value?  For example (I assigned `search` a `MagicMock` object because according to your description it probably has to be.  For the sake of the following example it would not be necessary that `search` is a `MagicMock` or any kind of mock):

```
# setup
search = MagicMock()
# when exercised, your code under test would do:
search.query = 42
# afterwards you validate that search.query holds the value you expect:
self.assertTrue(hasattr(search, 'query'))
self.assertEqual(search.query, 42)
```